# bash, issue on if condition

Tags: string, bash, if-statement

I'm trying to follow these explanations on if condition: http://linuxconfig.org/bash-printf-syntax-basics-with-examples

My code is

```
#!/bin/bash

result="test"
if [$result = "test"];
then printf "ok"
fi
```

But I have the following error:
line 4: [test: command not found

Comment: Debug your syntax with [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[` is a command. There must be spaces between not only it and its first argument, but between *every* argument.

Comment: additionally requires the space before `]` for same reason

Comment: Right, because `]` is an argument.

Answer (score 1):

In `bash` (and also POSIX shells), `[` is equivalent to [test](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) command, except that it requires `]` as the last argument. You need to separate command and its arguments for the shell doing [token recognition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03) correctly.

In your case, `bash` think `[test` is a command instead of command `[` with argument *test*. You need:

```
#!/bin/bash

result="test"
if [ "$result" = "test" ]; then
  printf "ok"
fi
```

(Note that you need to quote variables to prevent `split+glob` operators on them)